# Control ssh server “dynamically” and serve in different ports

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

I have a Linux machine that runs Garuda Linux. I want to control my SSH server as I want without interrupting (restarting). For example I want to disable/enable X11 forwarding, disable/enable root login, allow/prevent users from login etc. How to do it (if it is possible)? I don't want to edit the `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` file and restart the service every time.

Also, how to allow different ports for SSH server (e.g. port 22 and 2222 will both be used for SSH)? Is it possible to turn on/off one of them without interrupting the other? Is it possible to generate different keys for different ports?

In case dynamic control of SSH is not possible, can I use different ports to start SSH server with different configurations?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do these things without editing sshd config and bouncing the daemon.  You may want to explain *why* you're not willing to do that.  (For example, perhaps you fear that doing this remotely will kill an *existing* sessions.  It doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run two instances of sshd on different ports with different `sshd_config` files.

Use the [`-f` parameter of the `sshd`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#f) to specify the path to the instance-specific configuration file.